# SFMC LookupRows query result display question

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

as we know we can use lookupRow function in SFMC to query the data from the DE. and we also have LookupOrderedRows() function take same action and can sort the result.
my question is when we use lookupRow function query the data, the result display order is same as the data? or is will be radom? as my test, it looks like will same as DE'S content display order.

Answer (score 1):

With LookupRows the order you get is the order you see in the data extension.

Example

```
set @rows = LookupRows("DENAME","attribute", @attribute)
set @row = Row(@rows,1) /* return row number 1 */
```

This row will be the first row you see in the data extension with this attribute, not a randomly selected row! If I understand your question correctly, it seems to be aligned with your assumption

Comment: thanks for your upadtes, it's same as my thought, But no relevant instructions were found...

Comment: Can you please clarify your question then?

Comment: for example, I have a De, the first row stored A, the second ros stored  B, the third row stored C. currently I use lookuprows function and I can get the result as default order,"A,B,C". that's what I wanted result. my question is does it can got the result as "B,C,A" OR "C,B,A"? or I need use LookupOrderedRows() function to keep the  sort order?

Comment: If there is some kind of system or logic to the order you want rows in, then I believe it can be made with lookuprows, however I would need some more specific details about this use case to say for sure.

One way would be to change the number in Row(@rows, @number) with an ampscript variable that is defined logically and not just as an increment. 

Hope this helps